# NullInjectorError: Custom Angular Material CdkOverlay ref

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

I ran out to issue when create custom cdkOverlay popover component. It opens in table by clicking on filter icon. Table has few such icon.
Thats how look my Popover component service. It's open as an ordinary angular material dialog.

```
@Injectable()
export class PopoverService {
  constructor(
    private overlay: Overlay,
    private injector: Injector
  ) { }

  open<T = unknown, R = unknown>(component: ComponentType<T>, elementRef: ElementRef, config: PopoverConfig = {}): PopoverRef<R> {
    const popoverConfig: PopoverConfig = { ...DEFAULT_CONFIG, ...config };

    const overlayRef: OverlayRef = this.overlay.create(this.getOverlayConfig(elementRef, popoverConfig));

    const popoverRef: PopoverRef<R> = new PopoverRef<R>(overlayRef);

    const popupPortal: ComponentPortal<T> =
      new ComponentPortal<T>(component, null, this.createInjector(this.injector, popoverRef, config.data));

    overlayRef.attach(popupPortal);

    overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(_ => popoverRef.close());

    return popoverRef;
  }

  private createInjector(injector: Injector, popoverRef: PopoverRef, data: unknown): Injector {
    return Injector.create({
      providers: [
       { provide: PopoverRef, useValue: popoverRef },
       { provide: POPOVER_DATA, useValue: data }
      ],
      parent: injector
    });
  }

  private getOverlayConfig(elementRef: ElementRef, config: PopoverConfig): OverlayConfig {
    return new OverlayConfig({
      ...config,
      positionStrategy: this.getOverlayPositions(elementRef),
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition()
    });
  }

  private getOverlayPositions(elementRef: ElementRef): PositionStrategy {
    return this.overlay.position()
      .flexibleConnectedTo(elementRef)
      .withPositions(this.getPositions())
      .withFlexibleDimensions(false)
      .withPush(false);
  }

  private getPositions(): ConnectedPosition[] {
    return [
      {
        originX : 'center',
        originY : 'bottom',
        overlayX: 'start',
        overlayY: 'top',
      },
      {
        originX : 'center',
        originY : 'top',
        overlayX: 'start',
        overlayY: 'bottom',
      },
      {
        originX : 'center',
        originY : 'bottom',
        overlayX: 'end',
        overlayY: 'top',
      },
      {
        originX : 'center',
        originY : 'top',
        overlayX: 'end',
        overlayY: 'bottom',
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

I create also PopoverRef class, what include reference to overlay.

```
export class PopoverRef<T = unknown>{
  afterClosed$ = new Subject<OverlayCloseEvent<T>>();

  constructor(private overlayRef: OverlayRef) {
    overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => this.overlayClose('backdropClick', null));
  }

  close(data?: T): void {
    this.overlayClose('close', data);
  }

  private overlayClose(type: 'backdropClick' | 'close', data: T) {
    this.overlayRef.dispose();
    this.afterClosed$.next({
      type,
      data
    });

    this.afterClosed$.complete();

  }
}
```

component inside popover pass data to parent via `this.popoverRef.close(profile)`

and I expect that in parent component i can do such thing and receive a data `this.popoverRef.afterClosed$.subscribe((res) => this.someEmitter.emit(res))`

but as a result I see error in console

> **ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(TableModule)[PopoverRef -> PopoverRef -> PopoverRef -> PopoverRef -> PopoverRef -> PopoverRef]:
>
> NullInjectorError: No provider for PopoverRef!**

but everything works fine if afterClosed$ subscribe inside popover component

**UPDATED**
Parent component

```
  @ViewChild(CdkOverlayOrigin) cdkOverlayOrigin: CdkOverlayOrigin;
  @Input() filterType: TableFilterType;
  @Input() filterData: TableStaticData[];

  constructor(
    private popoverRef: PopoverRef
  ) {}

  onOpenPopover(event: Event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.popoverStore.dispatch(new fromPopoverStore.OpenFilterPopover({
      filterType: this.filterType,
      elRef: this.cdkOverlayOrigin.elementRef,
      filterItemData: this.filterItemData
    }));

    this.popoverRef.afterClosed$.subsribe();
  }
```

Comment: Well you try to inject PopoverRef somewhere and it is not included in this code, so we cannot help you.

Comment: parent component open popover, child component pass data via ```this.popoverRef.close(someData)```
in parent component i try ```this.popoverRef.afterClosed$.subscribe()``` parent coponent inject PopoverRef in constructor and this parent component has error

Comment: Care to post the code of the parent component (into the actual question)?

Comment: Your parent cannot inject PopoverRef in the constructor.

Comment: added parent component.

Anyway it didn't give me an answer, why i can't inject it to parent, it's normall for angular inject class even if it's not Injectable (OverlayRef class as example)
and what a solution to pass data to parent component

Answer (score 0):

For every service/value/whatever to be injected you need to have a provider.

1. There is a difference between injection dependencies into constructor and calling it directly. You're not injecting `OverlayRef` anywhere. You're calling the constructor of `PopoverRef` and passing the `OverlayRef`to it as an argument.
2. There is no provider for `PopoverRef` outside the Injector you manually create in the service. That injector is only used for components that are created in the `open` method of your service. Outside these components, you cannot access the `PopoverRef`

So, when the `popoverRef` is inaccessible in the parent component and you need it there, there are multiple solutions. You can create a service to store reference to the popover, you can change the logic how it is opened...

I suggest you should move the opening logic a level up. If you need to be able to trigger the popover in the child, then use an output.

```
@Component({selector: 'child-component', ...})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() openPopover = new EventEmitter<void>;
  
  onButtonClick() { this.openPopover.emit() }
}


@Component({template: `<child-component (openPopover)="openPopover()"></child-component>`})
export class ParenComponent {
  constructor(private popoverService) {}
  openPopover() { const popoverRef = this.popoverService.open(); // now you have access }
}
```

Comment: PopoverRef manualy injected in PopoverService in this method 
`private createInjector(injector: Injector, popoverRef: PopoverRef, data: unknown): Injector {
    return Injector.create({
      providers: [
       { provide: PopoverRef, useValue: popoverRef },
       { provide: POPOVER_DATA, useValue: data }
      ],
      parent: injector
    });`

Comment: That injector is only used for components that are created in the open method of your service. Outside these components, you cannot access the PopoverRef